# Image is not being shown when using UIImage imageWithData:NSData dataWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimageview

The below code is not displaying the image which is downloaded from online and written into my application documents directory.
i have checked inside the iphone's simulator documents directory , the downloaded file is exist.
but the image is not displayed.

When trying to add a resources image using `UIImage *imgBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"];` , the uiimageview displays the image.bu the image which is downloaded from online and stored inside the app directory is not displaying the image.

Pls let me know and thanks

```
NSString *workSpacePath=[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:theFileName];
NSLog(@"%@ workSpacePath ",workSpacePath);
if ( workSpacePath ){

        //--------------
       UIImage *imgBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"];
       imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)] autorelease];
       [imageView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

       imageView1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]];
       [cell addSubview:imageView1];
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the workSpacePath? Is it displaying the correct path of the image?

Comment: hope this link will help you , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037432/saving-image-to-documents-directory-and-retrieving-for-email-attachment

Comment: yes it displays the correct path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ,this is perfectly working for me:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobiledevelopertips.com/images/logo-iphone-dev-tips.png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO]; 

    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *workSpacePath = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"]; 
    NSLog(@"%@ workSpacePath ",workSpacePath);

if ( workSpacePath )
     {
        imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,20,20)];
        [imageView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView1];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of first converting the file to `NSData`, you can use

`[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]`

directly to load a `image` with given path.