# Generate unique temporary file paths

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, unique, temporary-files

I want to generate unique file paths in Objective-C. I looked at `NSTemporaryDirectory()` but the closest I could get was to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215820/how-do-i-create-a-temporary-file-with-cocoa/) and [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html). But in the second one they create such a file. I do not want to create it, I just want an NSString for a unique writable path... I don't need paths to folders, just files. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create file name using present system date and time (`[[NSCalendarDate calendarDate] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%m%d%Y%H%M%S%F"]`) .... this include even milliseconds ... use  returning string as unique file name ....

Read more about date formates -> http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/LegacyNSCalendarDate.html

Comment: Yes, I can, but who says they're unique? Perhaps another app has already a file with the same name there.

Comment: There are deferent approaches to handle above mentioned issue
1. Have folder with your appName where you want to create a file and keep file inside it.(if you are in iPhone app is in sandbox no issue)
2. Have prefix for file name <AppNAME>_<FileName> (you can have app name or some constant string may be a HASH code)
3. Check is there a file of your choice if there is one then generate one more time, since you get different name in every micro second you should get a unique name with some number of iteration of try.
4.Even you can have combination all 3 option for better result