# How do I archive an NSArray of NSDictionary (with NSCoding)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Suppose I am holding data in an array like this

```
wordList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while ([rs next])     //Some database return loop
{
    wordDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [wordDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[rs intForColumn:@"id"]] forKey:@"id"];
    [wordDict setObject:[rs stringForColumn:@"word"] forKey:@"word"];

    [wordList addObject: wordDict];

    [wordDict release];
    wordDict = nil;
}
```

But I want to store this result (i.e. wordList) in SQLite for later use - I guess using `NSCoding`. How would I do that?
(Feel free to point out any errors in how stuff is being alloc'ed if there are problems there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t insist on serialization using `NSCoding`, there’s a `writeToFile:atomically:` method both on `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. This will serialize your object into a property list (`*.plist`). The only catch is that all the objects in the “tree” to be serialized must be `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` (see the documentation). I’m not sure how `NSNumber` fits in, but with a bit of luck it will be serialized and deserialized too. The inverse method that will turn the file back into a dictionary or an array is called `initWithContentsOfFile:`.

As for your code, I would just use the `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` convenience method that gets you an autoreleased dictionary. It’s shorter than the usual `alloc` & `init` and you save one line for the explicit release.

Comment: `NSNumber` and `NSDate` both work fine in plists.  Also don't need `wordDict = nil;`

Comment: Can I use something similar if I store the result in Database (SQLite) rather than writing to a file?

Comment: The property list is a string, you can store it almost anywhere. I’m just not sure if it’s the best idea, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: I have a very big database and I'm doing live search on it. However much I've optimized it, it's not *quite* as fast as I'd like - but acceptable. However, if I make a key for the search that someone has made (which has a LIMIT 20) then I can store this, and subsequent searches will be much faster. I don't want the app to go over 20 megs so I can't do this in advance. (Could you edit your answer and just add how to create the plist)

Comment: Aha. In that case you might ask a new question about query caching or database optimization? Because storing another column with structured string data does not sound optimal. ¶ Creating the plist string is easy, just create a [temporary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215820) using the methods mentioned above and then read the file contents into a string (there’s a special initializer just for that).