# Play audio files from sqlite database Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, audio

I'm storing about 40 000 audio files, 5K-7K each, in an sqlite database. I fetch the blob as an NSData object. What's the best way to play the audio file? I've been using ObjectAL to play audio files from disk, but I can't get it to play files from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class.
It has an `initWithData:` method:

```
- ( id )initWithData: ( NSData * )data error: ( NSError ** )outError;
```

Since you already have `NSData` objects, it should be pretty straightforward.

Alternatively, you may also [create a temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215820/how-do-i-create-a-temporary-file-with-cocoa) with the data.