# Accessing temp directory in Swift

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

I was trying to access temp directory in Swift. In Objective-C, I could use the following code to do so:

```
- (NSString *)tempDirectory {

    NSString *tempDirectoryTemplate =
    [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XXXXX"];
    const char *tempDirectoryTemplateCString = [tempDirectoryTemplate fileSystemRepresentation];
    char *tempDirectoryNameCString           = (char *)malloc(strlen(tempDirectoryTemplateCString) + 1);
    strcpy(tempDirectoryNameCString, tempDirectoryTemplateCString);
    char *result                             = mkdtemp(tempDirectoryNameCString);
    if (!result) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSString *tempDirectoryPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:tempDirectoryNameCString length:strlen(result)];
    free(tempDirectoryNameCString);
    return tempDirectoryPath;
}
```

However, I'm a bit confuse about the type conversion and casting from Objective-C to Swift, such as  `const char *` or `CMutablePointer<CChar>`. Is there any documents that I should look into?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about something like :

```
public extension FileManager {
    func createTempDirectory() throws -> String {
        let tempDirectory = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: tempDirectory,
                                                withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                attributes: nil)
        return tempDirectory
    }
}
```

It doesn't answer your question about char* but it's cleaner...

NSFileManager reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:).

Also check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215820/how-do-i-create-a-temporary-file-with-cocoa) regarding unique names.

Comment: Note that the BSD function `mkdtemp()` is different from the NSFileManager `createDirectoryAtPath` method because it creates a *unique directory name* from the given template.

Comment: @Grimxn Thanks! I'll try it later. BTW seems `createDirectoryAtPath(path: String!, attributes: NSDictionary!)` is deprecated, now it's `createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`. And does that means I could use `createFileAtPath()` to create a temp file with the same method?

Comment: @MartinR so I'd need to create my unique name if I use createDirectoryAtPath?

Comment: Check out the SO link I added to my answer - they deal with creating unique names.

Comment: @Grimxn I did something like `NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(NSUUID.UUID().UUIDString.substringToIndex(5))`. Thanks again!

Comment: You should not use error as Pointer. You should use var error: NSError and use the ampersand to get the address, so you can use the error. How do you dereference the NSErrorPointer?

Answer (score 11):

According to Apple, use of `NSTemporaryDirectory` is discouraged:

> See the FileManager method url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:) for the
> preferred means of finding the correct temporary directory. For more
> information about temporary files, see File System Programming Guide.

So instead, you should use `FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory`

or if you want an unique path:

```
let extractionPath = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString, isDirectory: true)
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1409211-nstemporarydirectory#discussion is the primary source that backs up this answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 2.1** version:

```
func createTempDirectory() -> String? {

    let tempDirURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("XXXXXX")

    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtURL(tempDirURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }

    return tempDirURL.absoluteString
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3 and up**

I think a good way to do this in swift is with an extension on FileManager. This should create a unique temporary folder and return the URL to you.

```
extension FileManager{

    func createTemporaryDirectory() throws -> URL {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)

        try createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        return url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3** version

```
func createTempDirectory() -> String? {

    guard let tempDirURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("myTempFile.xxx") else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: tempDirURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }

    return tempDirURL.absoluteString
}
```

Comment: A couple of things for other people wanting to use this: 1> You've made a URL with a file extension, and are creating a folder at it, and 2>, this will return nil if the directory already exists, which might be the behaviour you (and the original poster) want, but in most cases the user will probably want a result even if the directory already exists.  (Both of these things are untested, but unless Swift behaves differently to Obj-C this is the results I would expect)

Answer (score 3):

A direct translation of your Objective-C code to Swift would be:

```
func tempDirectory()->String! {
    let tempDirectoryTemplate = NSTemporaryDirectory()  + "XXXXX"
    var tempDirectoryTemplateCString = tempDirectoryTemplate.fileSystemRepresentation().copy()
    let result : CString = reinterpretCast(mkdtemp(&tempDirectoryTemplateCString))
    if !result {
        return nil
    }
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let tempDirectoryPath = fm.stringWithFileSystemRepresentation(result, length: Int(strlen(result)))
    return tempDirectoryPath
}
```

It uses the same `mkdtemp()` BSD method as your original code. This method creates
a directory name from the template which is guaranteed not to exist at the time where
the method is called.

Thanks to Nate Cook who figured out that `reinterpretCast()` can be used to treat the `UnsafePointer<CChar>` returned  by `mkdtemp()` as a `CString`, so that it can be passed to `stringWithFileSystemRepresentation()`, see [Working with C strings in Swift, or: How to convert UnsafePointer<CChar> to CString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418955/working-with-c-strings-in-swift-or-how-to-convert-unsafepointercchar-to-cstr).

---

As of Xcode 6 beta 6, the `reinterpretCast()` is not necessary anymore and the
above code can be simplified to

```
func tempDirectory()->String! {
    let tempDirectoryTemplate = NSTemporaryDirectory()  + "XXXXX"
    var tempDirectoryTemplateCString = tempDirectoryTemplate.fileSystemRepresentation()
    let result = mkdtemp(&tempDirectoryTemplateCString)
    if result == nil {
        return nil
    }
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let tempDirectoryPath = fm.stringWithFileSystemRepresentation(result, length: Int(strlen(result)))
    return tempDirectoryPath
}
```