# iOS Dropbox error loading thumbnails

Tags: ios, swift, thumbnails, dropbox

I wanna get thumbnails for dropbox files that I display on a view. I know that I've to use the `loadThumbnail` method, but I don't get exactly how to do it.

I wrote this :

```
for file in dropboxMetadata.contents {
        dbRestClient.loadThumbnail(file.path, ofSize: "s", intoPath: "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/thumbnails/auto/")
}
```

but I get some errors like this :

```
error making request to /1/thumbnails/dropbox/star.jpg - (4) Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: show your "`- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedThumbnail:(NSString *)destPath metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata`" implementation

Comment: The `intoPath` needs to be a location that you can write to locally.

Comment: If I'm right, I have to put thumbnails on my own url ? @MichaelDautermann I haven't saw this method, so I can put images in my view in this method when thumbnails are ready ?

Comment: So I replaced the method by this : `client.loadThumbnail("https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/thumbnails/auto/", ofSize: "s", intoPath: "http://myUrl")`                                                                                       and I got this error : `error making request to /1/thumbnails/dropboxhttps://api-content.dropbox.com/1/thumbnails/auto - (400) Expected 'root' to be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto', got u'dropboxhttps:'`

Comment: path is a file system path and not a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Petesh has the right idea.  `intoPath` is the destination directory for those thumbnails.

Try this:

```
    func createTempDirectory() -> String? {
    let tempDirectoryTemplate = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("XXXXX")

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var err: NSErrorPointer = nil

    // remove any previous temporary folder that's there, in case it's there
    fileManager.removeItemAtPath(tempDirectoryTemplate)

    if fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(tempDirectoryTemplate, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: err) {
        return tempDirectoryTemplate
    } else {
        print("can't create temporary directory at \(tempDirectoryTemplate)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

The above code for which I found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281362/accessing-temp-directory-in-swift)

Then you could change your own code to do something like:

```
let temporaryDirectory = createTempDirectory()
for file in dropboxMetadata.contents {
        dbRestClient.loadThumbnail(file.path, ofSize: "s", intoPath: temporaryDirectory)
}
```

If this works, then you could change the "`intoPath`" parameter into any directory you think is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to really work ! Now I wonder how to get thumbnails, are they called by their name in the url ? Something like : `var imageName = temporaryDirectory + "/star.jpg" ` ?

Comment: I suspect so, but you can list out the files in that folder and see what you can find.  [Here is another useful question & answer that might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285016/swift-iterate-through-files-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders).

Comment: Thanks, but when I print `temporaryDirectory`, it return nil. Is that right ?

Comment: how & where are you printing it? I added a couple lines to the temporary directory creation code up there.

Comment: I declared `tempDirectoryTemplate` and did `stringByAppendingPathComponent` after and it works. It return that : `Optional("/Users/simpleandnew2/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2F8FD9AD-0EA5-4DE9-B2E3-553B374049EA/data/Containers/Data/Application/37567AC9-ECDC-46A4-8FFB-E0AAF1E0E4BF/tmp/")`

Comment: Looks like it's working well for the simulator.  You also may want to change my code so instead of deleting the temp directory (and the files inside it) each time it runs, you simply check for the existence of that directory and if it doesn't exist, then go ahead and create it.

Comment: Thanks, but the error in my question `error making request to /1/thumbnails/dropbox/star.jpg`is always displaying, and I don"t understand why

Comment: Okay!  I give up for now.  Perhaps somebody else can answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael you helped me a lot