# How do I get the temp directory in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, temp

How do I get the temp directory in iOS using Swift? I use this code, but I get the following error:

```
let localTempURL: URL = try defaultFileManager.url(for: .itemReplacementDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)

I found this post, but it's [old non-preferred way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281362/accessing-temp-directory-in-swift). I would like to be able to get the temp directory using FileManager.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:).

Comment: `FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory` didn't work for you?

Comment: @TheTiger I'm not able to use temporaryDirectory because the iOS version I'm coding for is older. Last time I looked that was for iOS 11 Beta. I'm coding for iOS 10.

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nstemporarydirectory/

Comment: @ShinehahGnolaum Just checked [From the XCode](https://i.imgur.com/QAFFEtz.png)

Comment: @TheTiger Yes. I checked the documentation. I got confused. I also checked my project settings. I was set to be backward compatible to iOS 8. That is probably unnecessary.